# What is the maximum char value in a java program in Netbeans IDE/ what is wrong with my program?

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode

What is the maximum Unicode value of a char in Java (in particular in the Netbeans IDE, if that makes any difference) I've been trying to write a program that, as part of the program, multiplies a char by a random number. According to what I've heard, based on the maximum Unicode value I should be able to multiply the highest value char I'm using (the tilde) by at least 8000 without causing overflow, however overflow does occur in my program. Is there a difference between the maximum Unicode char value and the maximum that is available in Netbeans? In case that isn't the case I have included my code below:

EDIT What I want to do with this portion of the program is "encrypt" the password by multiplying the char with a random number, and then I included a separate section meant to "decrypt" said code, however testing with smaller numbers I found that that part worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pass = "Password";
    String pwE = "";
    int key [] = new int[pass.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++)
    {
        key[i] = (int)(Math.random()*8000+1); /*EDIT changed the placeholder to the actual function I'm using */
        System.out.println(key[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++)
    {
        pwE += (char)(pass.charAt(i)*key[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(pwE);
    pass = "";

     for (int i = 0; i < pwE.length(); i++)
    {
        pass += (char)(pwE.charAt(i)/key[i]);
    }    
    System.out.println(pass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A char is a 16 bit unsigned type in Java.

Its maximum value is 65535.

Your multiplication of a char by an element of key looks suspect to me. Your casting this result (which will be an int type) back to char causes wraparound modulo 65536.

Your suspecting Netbeans is a red herring.

Very crudely, if your string only uses ASCII characters, then a maximumum multiplication of 512 would work.

Comment: Thank you. What datatype would you suggest that I use instead to make use of the full range of values available?

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a difference between the maximum Unicode char value and the maximum that is available in Netbeans [sic]?"

No, of course not. NetBeans doesn't have its own private, non-compliant version of Java. The maximum value of a `char` is always `Character.MAX_VALUE`, as documented.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE

Your problem is very likely caused by your use of `String` to drive "encryption" and "decryption". You don't bother to control the string encoding, and that could conceivably create strangeness with respect to surrogate pairs and the like. You're mixing the numeric nature of `char` with `String`'s use of the type to represent characters.

Since you didn't bother to share inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs with us, we can only guess. Perhaps if you were to share sufficient information ...

Comment: I just added some extra info. Excuse my ignorance but I am fairly new to coding, what do you mean by String encoding? Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: A search online for "String encoding Unicode" will reveal much, but an encoding is a mapping of numeric values like `65` to characters like `A`, and there are many encodings. ASCII encodes 127 characters into single-byte values, for example. Trouble is that there are over 100,000 characters already standardized, more than can be mapped by a `char`, let alone a byte. So there are a few flavors of _Unicode_ mappings, or encodings, including UTF-8 and UTF-16, that map strings to multi-byte or multi-char sequences. It's worth reading up on. Anyway, don't use `String` for encryption.